# How to fix react native expo starting code?

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

When I type the normal expo code and start my project, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/expo/react-native-maps.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Atharva Sawant\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-27T17_07_14_954Z-debug.log
Process exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Comment: try to delete node modules and install again. npm install

Comment: The same thing happens!

Answer (score 0):

I searched for errors and found a solution.

I drew up the answer by referring to [the link.](https://github.com/orktes/atom-react/issues/106#issuecomment-197328359)

I was able to get it to work by first installing Git for Windows as mentioned earlier https://git-for-windows.github.io/.

Then, instead of opening up a regular command prompt and issuing the apm install  command, go to your Windows Start menu and open up Git CMD. Run the command there and it should work.

or

you try add GIT to $PATH

If you can't use Set, try adding it using Setx.

Syntax example is:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin" /M
```

If you have any further questions, please leave a comment.

Comment: Still, it freezes after sometime

Comment: can you try `Cd Project_Dir>Set EXPO_DEBUG=ture`?